# Where is this date output coming from in json.Encoder?

Tags: go

At the end of [the JSON and Go blog post](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) you'll find this sample program:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
    enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    for {
        var v map[string]interface{}
        if err := dec.Decode(&v); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        for k := range v {
            if k != "Name" {
                delete(v, k)
            }
        }
        if err := enc.Encode(&v); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled this with `go build json_decoder.go` and then ran the program like so in bash:

```
echo '{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"]}' | json_decoder
```

and received this output:

```
{"Name":"Wednesday"}
2019/08/17 22:09:20 EOF
```

The first line of output is exactly what I'd expect.  But where is the line `2019/08/17 22:09:20 EOF` coming from?

Comment: `log.Println(err)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `EOF` is reached the decoder returns [`io.EOF`](https://godoc.org/io#pkg-variables) which is then is being output by the logger `log.Println(err)` with a timestamp prepended.

You can check for `EOF` when decoding like this for example

```
if err := dec.Decode(&v); err != nil {
    if err != io.EOF {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    return
}
```

Output:

```
➜ echo '{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"]}' | ./json_decoder
{"Name":"Wednesday"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
log.Println(err)
```

> That logger writes to standard error and prints the date and time of each logged message.

---

You are seeing both `stdout`and `stderr` so:

1. The solution is to **redirect** the `stdout` to a file (or to another pipe):

   ```
   echo '{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"]}' | ./jsonio > file.json
   ```

   Output (which is `stderr`):

   ```
   2019/08/17 20:35:40 EOF
   ```

   Then see the file content (which is `stdout`):

   ```
   cat file.json 

   {"Name":"Wednesday"}
   ```

---

2. You may discard `stderr` (not recommended, but for test purpose) or redirect `stderr`:

   ```
   echo '{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"]}' | ./jsonio 2>/dev/null
   ```

   Output (which is `stdout`):

   ```
   {"Name":"Wednesday"}
   ```

---

3. Or don't show the `EOF` at all (**note**: you'll see other errors like incorrect JSON errors in `stderr`):

   ```golang
   package main

   import (
       "encoding/json"
       "io"
       "log"
       "os"
   )

   func main() {
       dec := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
       enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
       for {
           var v map[string]interface{}
           if err := dec.Decode(&v); err != nil {
               if err != io.EOF {
                   log.Println(err)
               }
               return
           }
           for k := range v {
               if k != "Name" {
                   delete(v, k)
               }
           }
           if err := enc.Encode(&v); err != nil {
               log.Println(err)
           }
       }
   }
   ```